# property value overridden by parent even though set explicitly

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, properties, triggers

When I have a control `A` that contains a control `B`, there are properties `Prop` that are inherited. That means, `B.Prop` will automatically take the value of `A.Prop` **if `B.Prop` is not explicitly set**. As far as I know, `IsEnabled` is such a property.

Now I have a situation where I do set the value of `B.IsEnabled` explicitly, and still it is overwritten by the value of `A.IsEnabled`. **Why is that so, and how can I correct it?**

In this situation `A` is a StackPanel and `B` a TextBox:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InDisableMode}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <TextBox Text="some text">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InDisableMode}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

The above XAML snippet has its DataContext set to my ViewModel. The ViewModel contains a property `InDisableMode` which is a `bool`. When it is `false`, everything is as expected: The StackPanel is enabled and the TextBox is disabled.

But when `InDisableMode` is `true`, both the StackPanel and the TextBox are disabled although both Triggers should trigger!

Note: I know I can databind `IsEnabled` to `InDisableMode` in both controls (in the TextBox directly, in the StackPanel by using a complement converter). I have not tried if this works since I want to do this with Triggers anyway.

EDIT:

The point of disabling the StackPanel is to disable all of its children easily (except the TextBox which I want to enable instead). Any other ideas how to solve this task without changing the parent-child-relationship or creating new controls? At the moment, the only way I see is to disable all children except the TextBox one by one...

Answer (score 1):

If you disable a control, its children are disabled. Since a `StackPanel` is not interactive, there is no reason to disable it other than to disable its interactive children.

If you want to enable a control A while its parent B is disabled, you can't do that. B cannot be the parent if you want to enable A while B is disabled.

For a workaround, you can put them both in a `Grid`, with the `TextBox` defined last, to superimpose the `TextBox` on top of the `StackPanel`. Then it will be within the `StackPanel`'s area but it won't be a child of the `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `UIElement.IsEnabled` property uses value coercion by inheriting the value from its parent. This it does by using `CoerceValueCallback`. Value coercion is ranked first in [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)

So, to override this behavior, we have two options. Firstly, to use `AddOwner()` to register our type as new owner of `IsEnabled` property. Secondly, to override the metadata using `OverrideMetadata()`. This second method would work only if you inherit directly from `UIElement`.

So, lets say we want our `Button` to behave differently, we should create a new `Button` like below :

```
public class CButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabled;

    static CButton()
    {
        IsEnabled = UIElement.IsEnabledProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CButton), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, 
                    UIElement.IsEnabledProperty.DefaultMetadata.PropertyChangedCallback,
                    new CoerceValueCallback(IsEnabledCoerceCallback)));
    }

    private static object IsEnabledCoerceCallback(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {            
        return (bool) baseValue;
    }
}
```

Here, we are returning assigned value as it is from `IsEnabledCoerceCallback`. Before returning, you can also introduce the behavior : If user doesn't provide any value for `IsEnabled`, then use inherited value from parent, else use `CButton.IsEnabled` user assigned value.

On a side note, try setting `null` in place of `new CoerceValueCallback(IsEnabledCoerceCallback)` , see what happens.

Comment: "This happens because UIElement.IsEnabled property uses value coercion by inheriting the value from its parent." - but if the child always inherits the value from its parent, why is it possible to have the parent enabled and child disabled?

Comment: @Kjara Inheriting and over-writing are two diff cases. Coercing means you want to over-write the default behavior. Label.FontSize = 20 will change fontsize of all textblocks inside it, but if you set FontSize of a particular one, that will be respected.